# It wont let me upgrade to ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, upgrade

I want to upgrade from Ubuntu 12.10 to Ubuntu 13.04 but I cant.  I downloaded the iso of Ubuntu 13.04 but it's only allowing a clean install.  The "software updater" (update manager as it was called in 12.04) only offers an upgrade to Xubuntu.

Is there a way to upgrade to what I want?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following command in the terminal:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```